# What was Thor-2014 doing when current Thor on Asgard?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, thor-the-dark-world

Present Thor and Rocket go to Asgard to get the Reality Stone,

Then Present Thor says that his mother is going to die today, then meets his mother and he gets his hammer and goes to future.

What was Past Thor doing at that time?

He needs his hammer that day to fight with dark-elves right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't know the exact time when old Thor went there. So, we can assume that 2014-Thor was busy doing some stuff on Asgard, either talking with Odin or Loki. However, fighting off dark elves have a less possibility since we don't see anything that seems like a fight at that time.

Of course, he'd require his hammer to fight with dark elves and he will use it. However, this hammer was [returned](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/99740/27264) by Captain America already before 2014-Thor came to know that it has been taken.

Comment: We know new Thor was there when his mother was scheduled to die that day, did that happen during a movie or was that off screen? Thor did quip, assuming I remembered correctly, *"today's the day my mother dies"*

Comment: I am not saying he wasn't there.

Comment: No, but we can work out roughly when his mother died and have possible points where old Thor could be, if his mother's death happened during a movie. That was my main question, when did Thor's mother die during the movies?

Comment: It seems that his mother was either going to meet Loki or Jane at that time.

Comment: First, Thor brings Jane to Asgard. She's allowed to sleep. Then Rocket steals the stone/ aether. Then Thor introduces Jane and Frigga. Then the Dark Elves sack Asgard. https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Jane_Foster

Answer (score 1):

As Hulk mentions, the plan is to return the stones to that near same instant so that that timeline wouldn't feel the missing effect of the stone. Now the same applies to the hammer too.

The way I see things would have panned out is like this:

- Thor and Rocket leave with the Hammer and Aether.
- Soon as that happens Steve shows up with the Hammer and Aether.

We don't know how Steve would do it but he'd return the Aether ... into Jane, and put the hammer on a nearby table or whatever. So as far as that timeline is concerned, the Hammer and Aether went missing for just a minute.

When 2014-Thor calls for his hammer, it would show up with a minute's delay and he can be off fighting the Dark Elves.